# connect to existing EC2 instance using cloud9

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud9

Recently I setup and Amazon EC2 Linux AMI instance to host the ECR and want to connect it to the awesome Cloud 9 IDE.
But somehow it cannot connect. I opened the SSH port on the EC2 instance, copied the the public SSH key value (from the cloud9 wizard) into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the existing instance, but getting the message:AWS Cloud9 couldn't connect to SSH server ec2-user@.....

What am I missing?

merci A

Comment: were you able to resolve this isssue? I am stuck with same problem.

Comment: @Em Ae yes; I solved it; in my case it had been a config issue. I deleted my AWS config file under ~/.aws and set it up anew along with new acces credentials. Once this was done it worked like a charm.